# Sorting Report Entries by Subgroup in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

This is what my data looks like now

- Task

  - SubTask
- Task

  - SubTask
  - SubTask
- Task

I was wondering if it would be possible to sort according to the number of subgroups using vba code (normal access report sorts break up the grouping) so that it ends up like

- Task

  - SubTask
  - SubTask
- Task

  - SubTask
- Task

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

In the query used by your report, group by Task and have a field:  `SubTasks: Count(SubTaskID)`
You can then sort by this field in the report.

Comment: What if I created my report from tables instead of a query? Then I would have to refer to an outside query, which the access report doesn't seem to allow me to do